# Angular ng-if not working from scope function(angular function)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I understand the concept that, **ng-if** creates its own scope for the variable inside it.

In the below code, i am enabling **Alert** (with Confirm and Cancel buttons) to be visible from **Show Alert** button, which  is doing its job.

But, evidently when i try to achieve the contrary, it is not working out. It seems that setting of showEditAlert has no effect on the **ng-if** block. This setting is being done using  **showConfirm()** call, which in turn sets the boolean value of **showEditAlert** to **false** (hide view), but instead , view remains enabled.

```
         //Triggers Alert to show onClick
         <button class="btn launchConfirm" ng-click="showEditAlert=true ">Show Alert</button>


         <div ng-if="showEditAlert">                   
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in " role="alert">                
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <strong style="color:black">Proceed with edit options Please confirm?</strong>

                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" 
                      ng-click="$parent.enable = false; ShowConfirm()" >
                    confirm
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs "
                      ng-click="$parent.showEditAlert=false">
                    cancel
                </button>                                                   
            </div>
        <div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.showEditAlert = false; //Initialization

$scope.ShowConfirm = function() {
    $scope.showEditAlert = false // This setting value is not effecting the ng-if block
 }
```

I know i am missing out with some **Scope** wise understanding, kindly help me out with clear picture. Would really appreciate the response.

**PS**. I have acquired the solution using **ng-show and ng-hide**. But, the intention is to achieve the same using **ng-if** (because, it directly has an effect on DOM)

Comment: Maybe you need to say `ng-if="myController.showEditAlert"`.

Comment: When you click on confirm it's hiding that area then what is your exact problem ?

Comment: do you have any error?

Comment: @Mohit , When i clik on showConfirm(), it is not hiding the area is my problem.

Comment: Try removing the $parent part.
Try just this: ng-click="showEditAlert = false"

Comment: @leMS, the parent scope cannot access the value set/unset in the child scope , if $parent not used.

Answer (score 0):

See the working example

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.showEditAlert = false; //Initialization

$scope.ShowConfirm = function() {
    $scope.showEditAlert = false // This setting value is not effecting the ng-if block
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
   //Triggers Alert to show onClick
         <button class="btn launchConfirm" ng-click="showEditAlert=true ">Show Alert</button>


         <div ng-if="showEditAlert">                   
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in " role="alert">                
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <strong style="color:black">Proceed with edit options Please confirm?</strong>

                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" 
                      ng-click="$parent.enable = false; ShowConfirm()" >
                    confirm
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs "
                      ng-click="$parent.showEditAlert=false">
                    cancel
                </button>                                                   
            </div>
        <div>
</div>
```

Comment: appreciate the response Mohit, but i ve got the same logic put up.. i guess there is some other code collision happening.. Let me check out ..

Comment: i ve  got the same logic put up

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine.

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

      $scope.showEditAlert = false; //Initialization

      $scope.ShowConfirm = function() {
          $scope.showEditAlert = false // This setting value is not effecting the ng-if block
       };
    }]);
    </script>
    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <button class="btn launchConfirm" ng-click="showEditAlert=true ">Show Alert</button>


         <div ng-if="showEditAlert">                   
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in " role="alert">                
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <strong style="color:black">Proceed with edit options Please confirm?</strong>

                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" 
                      ng-click="$parent.enable = false; ShowConfirm()" >
                    confirm
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs "
                      ng-click="$parent.showEditAlert=false">
                    cancel
                </button>                                                   
            </div>
         </div>
    </form>
```

plunkr
[here] (https://plnkr.co/edit/1D48TWXl8dInTlcVYjn3?p=preview)!

Comment: appreciate the response ciril, but i ve got the same logic put up.. i guess there is some other code collision happening.. Let me check out ..